# Tenant ID in Azure DevOps Pipeline Script Censored

Tags: powershell, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have a pipeline that reaches into a key vault and prints the resulting string to the ADO execution log. Part of the string contains the tenant ID, which inexplicably gets replaced with "***".

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/***/oauth2/token
```

The code is nothing sophisticated:

```
$var = Get-AzKeyVaultSecret -VaultName $(vaultname) -Name $(secretname) -AsPlainText
Write-Host $var
```

Setting aside the inherent issues with the pipeline's security concerns, how do I prevent this from getting censored?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks that one of your secret has the same value as your tentnat id. And in this case you can't overcome this as secrets are masked to do not reveal them in logs. However, this is only for logging and behind the scene url is correct.

Please check it [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/scripts/logging-commands?view=azure-devops&tabs=bash#examples-1)

```sh
echo "You can use macro replacement to get secrets, and they'll be masked in the log: $(secretSauce)"
```

produces:

```
You can use macro replacement to get secrets, and they'll be masked in the log: ***
```